# Radio buttons in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to have a default value for my radio buttons, but get flagged an NullReferenceException error.

```
    private void rbImperial_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            txtInches.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            lblInches.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            lblWeight.Text = "lbs";
            lblHeight.Text = "Feet";
    }

    private void rbMetric_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lblHeight.Text = "cm";
        txtInches.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        lblInches.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        lblWeight.Text = "kg";
    }
```

rbImperial is the defaulted radio button that should be checked.

XAML:

```
<RadioButton x:Name="rbMetric" Content="Metric" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="132,244,0,0" Checked="rbMetric_Checked" ClickMode="Press"/>
<RadioButton x:Name="rbImperial" Content="Imperial" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="132,199,0,0" Checked="rbImperial_Checked" IsChecked="True" ClickMode="Press" />
```

If I don't have the rbImperial Checked property to be True to make it defaulted to be selected it runs perfectly fine.

What am I missing?

My issue when I try to run it.

[image]

Comment: That is not how we do things in WPF apps. You don't subscribe to radio button checked event and set properties of other UI elements in code-behind or event handler. Learn about data binding, MVVM and triggers...

Comment: I mocked up your example and experienced no problems. Are you sure it is not something else giving null reference? Something in the Checked event handler probably because setting default to checked will make the handler run.

Comment: Josh, there has to be a bigger problem at hand.  The code you wrote should not give you any `Null` exceptions as far as the radio buttons are concerned.  Could you give us the error that is being produced in its entirety (the message and all).  However, as you see already, going the code-behind route is problematic, especially as you make further progress with your code.  @DeanK. made an observation that you should probably look into data binding and MVVM... and I have to agree.  Believe me, when I was new, I chose your route, because it was easy, but I abandoned it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the default value in the constructor. Not the prettiest method, but it should work. Alternatively, you can bind it to the ViewModel; that should work as well.